# Calendar in Vaadin for free

Tags: calendar, vaadin, add-on

I'm looking for free Vaadin calendar. 
I know, that there is a commercial add'on:

http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-calendar

Does anyone know any other free calendar implemented in Vaadin?

Answer (score 2):

Since February 2013, Vaadin Calendar is now free for everyone.  The license has changed to Apache 2.0 License.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I (as a Vaadin Ltd employee) know, a free implementation of a complete calendar component quite similar to the Vaadin Calendar add-on, has not been submitted to Vaadin directory or mentioned on the forum as of July 5th 2011. 
Please note that the Vaadin Calendar is free to use if your project is compatible with the [AGPL 3.0](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html) license.

The Vaadin [DateField](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#Dates) component provides some basic date picking functionality if that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin Calendar is also available for free underwriting agpl license. Whether AGPL is suitable for your project is another question.